# What is the best way to stop your newborn hiccuping?

Tags: newborn, bottle-feeding

After feeds and burping sessions, my newborn hiccups quite a lot. Are there any tried and tested positions that help alleviate the hiccups?

Comment: Of possible interest: [Hiccups: A new explanation for the mysterious reflex](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/bies.201100194)

Answer (score 6):

My baby had reflux so hiccuping was especially problematic for her as it churned things up EVEN More.  So we had to work hard at getting all the gas out for her.

We found the traditional burping position didn't actually do this.  It was easier to burp her by placing her in a seated position on the adult's knee, with her legs dangling inward.  Since I am right-handed I'll describe it to you from my perspective:

1. Baby on my right knee facing to my left and held by my left arm. 
   While her head still need support, I used my forearm for her to
   "lean on" and cradled her chin in the palm of my left hand.  When
   she no longer needed the head support I simply let her lean with my
   arm across her chest.
2. Using my right hand I would then gently pat starting at her lower
   back in a quick repetative upward motion to her upper back.  Then, I
   would move my hand back down to her lower back and on the second
   pass rub in an upward motion.
3. After completing step two, two or three times, I would then cause
   her to lean forward a little more by moving my left arm accordingly.
   This usually caused a **huge** burp.

When we got a nice big burp, there were fewer hiccups, or at least the ones she had were more mild.

As the mom, I also watched what I ate very closely (kept a journal of my foods, how often she nursed and how much **and** journaled her symptoms as well as her foods when she started eating.  It was important to have the baby sitter help with the food/symptom journal, but it really proved helpful in looking for patterns.  I found that cruciferous foods (such as onions) often seemed to relate to more severe problems about a day later as did oily foods so I avoided those until she was no longer nursing.

Generally though, hiccups are more annoying for us to listen to (when we aren't giggling over how cute they are) than they are troublesome for the baby.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time commenting on a place like this. I'm a new mother at 21 with an 8 week old son. I am also a stay at home mother.

He still sleeps about 4 times a day and when i put him down at midnight with a 5 to 6 oz bottle, he's out till 6:30-7. He just started this, but he will get hiccups and I know to stop between every 2 oz to burp. He dosent want to and he cries so I let him finish how ever much he can take at that moment, then burp him. So i wrap him in in sunggie wrap and he will go to sleep 5 mins later I'll hear him with the hiccups. It is an every other day thing, maybe twice a day.

I tried the on the shoulder bounce back pat, rubbing tummy, and the pacifier. or forcing him to eat the last ounce, but none of them work. so he cries and not even 5 mins later. His hiccups will be gone and he'll be ready for his nap.

All babies are different, but I hope this helps people.  I know mines sad to let him cry but its like he knows what he's doing. And he seems happy after he gets rid of them all by his self.

Answer (score 1):

Hiccups are very common among the babies. They are caused by overfeeding or when a baby swallows too much air.

- Most of the times, hiccups will go away on their own. Otherwise a gentle massage on the baby’s back will help in getting rid of hiccups.
- Give him a pacifier or something to chew on, this can help relieve your baby’s hiccups.

**Here are few tips to prevent:**

- Hold the bottle at a 45-degree angle so that the air settles at the end of the bottle, therefore baby will not swallow the air.
- The hole in the bottle’s nipple should be of proper size. If it is too big the formula will flow too quickly and if it is too small your baby may gulp air.
- Feed your baby as soon as they seem hungry so that they drink slowly otherwise they may swallow excess air during a crying fit.
- During the feedings take a break and rub on the baby’s back to make the baby burp then resume feeding after your baby burps. This helps to bring up the trapped air that leads to hiccups.

If you feel your baby is uncomfortable, not feeding normally or not growing normally then talk with your paediatrician.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, a sudden change in temperature or just being cold can cause hiccups in children. When you move your baby away from your body you may be exposing its front side to some loss of temperature which in turn may cause hiccups. Is your baby swaddled and dressed appropriately to your home temperature?

Answer (score 0):

We offer the pacifier to help regulate his hiccups. Focusing on the sucking motion usually helps him get rid of his hiccups in a matter of minutes. Good luck!